# Get elements that has no double value in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a question . How do you retrieve elements that has no double value in an array?? For example: [1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5] then you retrieve [3,5] only.
Thanks in advance

```
for (var j = 0; j < newArr.length; j++) {
  if ((arr1.indexOf(newArr[j]) === 0) && (arr2.indexOf(newArr[j]) === 0)) {
    index = newArr.indexOf(j); newArr.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, that's a fair try, check my answer.

Comment: for (var i=0; i< concatted.length -1; i++){
    
    if (concatted[i] !== concatted[i+1]){
      newArr.push(concatted[i+1]);
      i += 2;
    }
  }

Answer (score 6):

If the item in the array is unique then the index found from the beginning should equal the index found from the end, in other words:

```js
var xs = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5];

var result = xs.filter(function(x) {
  return xs.indexOf(x) === xs.lastIndexOf(x);
});

console.log(result); //=> [3, 5]
```

Comment: That's a very elegant solution.

Comment: It is been 4 years or so but never heard of `lastIndexOf` ;( May be I am doing enough development!...+1

Comment: The second argument of `filter` callback is already the index of the current element. So there is no need for `xs.indexOf(x)` here.

Comment: @Tresdin, that wouldn't be the same, `indexOf` returns the _first_ index

Comment: @elclanrs Thanks a lot!

Comment: @elclanrs My bad. Using the current index will just remove the duplicated elements, not the element itself.

Answer (score 0):

create new array `tmp`,and check already value exist by `indexOf` .If existed delete by `splice` function..

```
var arr = [1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5];
var tmp = [];
var dup = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        var ind = tmp.indexOf(arr[i]);
        if(ind == -1){
         if(dup.indexOf(arr[i]) == -1){
               tmp.push(arr[i]);
           }
        }
        else{
        tmp.splice(ind,1);
        dup.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    console.log(tmp);
```

Comment: __If input is `[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]`__

Comment: @Rayon I see it's not work for more than double values ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A solution for unsorted arrays with a hash table for the items. Complexity **O(2n)**

```js
var array = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 1],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    single;

array.forEach(function (a, i) {
     hash[a] = a in hash ? -1 : i;
});

single = array.filter(function (a, i) {
    return hash[a] === i;
});

console.log(single);
```

Comment: May fail if `[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 1]`

Comment: Cool but in order to make the operation fail-safe you have to sort the array first.. then when it comes to sorting, i am pretty sure you can come up with much better ways of doing this without sorting. Like a `forEach` loop with an object hash table (provided through the `this` argument)

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the presentation its my first post ! 
You have to compare each element of your array to the others in order to get the number of occurence of each element

```
    var tab = [1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5] //The array to analyze
    tab = tab.sort(); // we sort the array
    show(tab); // we display the array to the console (F12 to open it)

    var uniqueElementTab = []; // this array will contain all single occurence

    var sameElementCounter = 0;
    for(x=0;x<tab.length;x++){ // for all element in the array
        sameElementCounter = 0;
        for(y=0;y<tab.length;y++){ // we compare it to the others
            if((tab[x]==tab[y])){
                sameElementCounter+=1; // +1 each time we meet the element elsewhere 
            }
        }
        if(sameElementCounter<=1){
            uniqueElementTab.push(tab[x]); //if the element is unique we add it to a new array
        }
    }
    show(uniqueElementTab); // display result

    function show(tab) { // Simple function to display the content of an array
        var st="";
        for(i=0;i<tab.length;i++){
            st += tab[i]+" ";
        }
        console.log(st+"\n");
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple "tricky" solution using `Array.sort`, `Array.join`, `Array.map`, `String.replace` and `String.split` functions:

```
var arr = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5];
arr.sort();
var unique = arr.join("").replace(/(\d)\1+/g, "").split("").map(Number);

console.log(unique);  // [3, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be my way of doing this job.

```js
var arr = [1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5],
uniques = Object.keys(arr.reduce((p,c) => (c in p ? Object.defineProperty(p, c, {enumerable : false,
                                                                                   writable : true,
                                                                               configurable : true})
                                                  : p[c] = c,
                                           p), {}));
console.log(uniques);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the array is sorted, you can solve this in O(n) (see "pushUniqueSinglePass" below):

```js
function pushUniqueSinglePass(array, unique) {
  var prev; // last element seen
  var run = 0; // number of times it has been seen
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] != prev) {
      if (run == 1) {
        unique.push(prev); // "prev" appears only once
      }
      prev = array[i];
      run = 1;
    } else {
      run++;
    }
  }
}

function pushUniqueWithSet(array, unique) {
  var set = new Set();
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    set.add(array[i]);
  }
  for (let e of set) {
    unique.push(set);
  }
}

// Utility and test functions

function randomSortedArray(n, max) {
  var array = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    array.push(Math.floor(max * Math.random()));
  }
  return array.sort();
}

function runtest(i) {
  var array = randomSortedArray(i, i / 2);
  var r1 = [],
    r2 = [];
  console.log("Size:        " + i);
  console.log("Single-pass: " + time(
    pushUniqueSinglePass, array, r1));
  console.log("With set:    " + time(
    pushUniqueWithSet, array, r2));
  // missing - assert r1 == r2
}

[10, 100, 1000, 10000,
  100000, 1000000
].forEach(runtest);


function time(fun, array, unique) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  fun(array, unique);
  return new Date().getTime() - start;
}
```

This is much more efficient than using maps or sorting (time it!). In my machine, a 1M sorted array can have its unique elements found in 18 ms; while the version that uses a set requires 10x more.